# One project my obj.save() returning object how i did not used commit=Fa;se

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Below code you will see that uf.save() statement returning the object how ? i did not use uf.save(commit=False)

```
def wash(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = Userform(request.POST)
        wf = Profileform(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if uf.is_valid() and wf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save()
            print(user)
            wf.instance.user = user
            wf.save()
            return HttpResponse("suscess fully crated ")
        return render(request, 'webpage/washer.html', {'wf': wf, 'uf': uf})
```

Comment: Regardless whether you use `save(commit=False)` or with `True`, it will return the object wrapped in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [**`.save(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) on a `ModelForm`, it will return the instance wrapped in the form, regardless whether `commit=True` (this is the case if you do not specify the `commit=…` parameter), or `commit=False`.

This is often used, for example like in this case where we use the instance of one form, to use this when we work with the second form.